# Algorithm for sport tournament bracket tree

Tags: algorithms, optimization, trees

I would like to develop a library that:

- receive n players in input
- response with the tournaments brackets in output.

I would ask you what kind of algorithm I have to use to choose the correct tree that have to be generated for each input.
I am interested on single elimination tournaments, and players of the same club you have to challenge as late as possible.

I found this basic algorithm:

```
   $players = range(1, 3);
$count = count($players);

// Order players.
$max = log($count / 2, 2);
echo "max ".$max."<br>";
for ($i = 0; $i < log($count / 2, 2); $i++) {
    $out = array();

    foreach ($players as $player) {
        $splice = pow(2, $i);

        $out = array_merge($out, array_splice($players, 0, $splice));

        $out = array_merge($out, array_splice($players, -$splice));
    }

    $players = $out;
}

// Print match list.
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    printf('%s vs %s<br />%s', $players[$i], $players[++$i], PHP_EOL);
}
```

What do you think? Is it a good solution?

The second question is how I can draw the bracket tree, any suggestion?
I have to use html/javascript.

Thank you.

Comment: If you do not have any particular criteria / restrictions, you can just randomly split groups of players into two subgroups of equal sizes, until all groups contain exactly two players. This assumes n = 2^k, for some k.

Comment: I found something that do your solution...I think it would be a good start. what do you think?